# Security strategies for sensitive transient data awaiting processing

Tags: security, system-design

I'm currently in alpha testing/development of a REST API-based service that performs automation tasks for clients on behalf of their users. The web application is hosted on my server and tasks are processed by workers running within a background service. There might be many instances of the service running across multiple servers, depennding on load.

The users create a session via the API, and the session is stored in the database and queued for processing. The user then issues commands for their session. A worker process dequeues the session and starts processing the commands, one by one, until the user closes the session. Command results are stored in the database for the user to access upon completion.

What would be a good strategy to ensure that command inputs are kept secure until they are processed, as they may contain sensitive data that should not be leaked. After processing, the inputs can be deleted, but I'd like to assure my users that the chance of leakage of any data that my system processes is negligible.